# Regular expression for only one url validation in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, validation, url

at present i am using following regular expression

```
/^(ftp|http|https):\/\/(\w+:{0,1}\w*@)?(\S+)(:[0-9]+)?(\/|\/([\w#!:.?+=&%@!\-\/]))?$/
```

it validating url like 
`https://scores.arrowsight.com/scores/ORoom/Hospital%20A1/Hospital%20A2` 
but it should not validate url like 
`http://www.google.co.in/http://www.google.co.in/`
above url should not allow but it allow `http://www.google.co.in/http://www.google.co.in/`
Can someone help me in modifying this? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Aside from needing to be URL encoded, that URL is valid.  If you put it in a browser, it would work.  Do you only want to allow URL safe characters?

Comment: ya that is valid but i want validation for only one url should be there not two urls...

Comment: Technically, that is one URL, but I understand what you mean.

Comment: @priyankapatel: There aren't two URLs. That URL is totally valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this regex with negative lookahead:

```
/^(ftp|https?):\/\/(\w+:{0,1}\w*@)?((?![^\/]+\/(?:ftp|https?):)\S+)(:[0-9]+)?(\/|\/([\w#!:.?+=&%@!\-\/]))?$/
```

[**Live Demo**](http://regexpal.com/?flags=g&regex=%5E%28ftp%7Chttps%3F%29%3A%5C%2F%5C%2F%28%5Cw%2B%3A%7B0%2C1%7D%5Cw%2a%40%29%3F%28%28%3F!%5B%5E%5C%2F%5D%2B%5C%2F%28%3F%3Aftp%7Chttps%3F%29%3A%29%5CS%2B%29%28%3A%5B0-9%5D%2B%29%3F%28%5C%2F%7C%5C%2F%28%5B%5Cw%23!%3A.%3F%2B%3D%26%25%40!%5C-%5C%2F%5D%29%29%3F%24&input=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.co.in%2Fhttps%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.co.in%2F%0A)

Comment: its only work for http://www.google.co.in/http://www.google.co.in/ not for https://scores.arrowsight.com/scores/ORoom/Hospital%20A1/Hospital%20A2&https://scores.arrowsight.com/

Comment: It can be modified a bit to disallow `(?:ftp|https?)` anywhere after first slash.